# Обработка пофайлово всех аудиофайлов в папке с сохранением результата в один файл на Python

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

Занимаюсь вычленением признаков в аудиофайлах на Python, в частности пользуюсь Анакондой. Есть готовые модели. Столкнулся с проблемой - требуется обработать наборы файлов ( в среднем 3500 шт в папке), вычленить признаки с последующим сохранением результата, в виде таблицы, в один файл в формате h5. 
Чтение, перебор организовал в формате:

```
root = 'c:\\scripts'
pattern = '*.py'
for folder, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
  for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
    fullname = os.path.join(folder, filename)
```

следом, в цикле `for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):` реализую вычленение признаков. 
все признаки складываю в один файл как:

```
x.append((chs/znam)**alpha) 
mgd = np.vstack(x)
print(mgd.shape)
np.savetxt('H:\\Magistr\\testdata\\mgd\\rezult_zn.csv', mgd, delimiter = ",")
```

В итоге как бы я не пробовал варьировать комбинацию stack для массива и `append` для списка. у меня из-за того что все происходит в цикле всегда сохраняется результат обработки последней итерации, обработки последнего файла. Как исправить?
P/s: я только начал заниматься Python, а вопрос надо закрыть в течение недели.

Comment: поясните как и какие признаки вы "вычленяте" из аудиофайлов и как вы их хотите объединить в таблицу перед записью в '.h5' ?

Comment: Признаки интересуют MGD, MFCC, PLP, LPCC, CQCC и их комбинации. Вообще я планировал их класть в массив, а далее через:
`with h5py.File("H:\\...\file.h5", "a") as hf:
    dset = hf.create_dataset('mgd-feature', data = array, dtype = 'float')`
класть в HDF5, где array массив в который я все собираю.
В данном случае это `mgd `, который я и не могу правильно сформировать.
Для каждого файла в отдельности у меня все получается, а мне надо для всех в папке в один файл.